# Evil in dired/dired+ keymapping

Tags: vim, emacs, dired, evil-mode

I'm looking for a way to navigate in dired/dired+ and evil mode by using 'h' 'j' 'k' 'l' like as in vim netrw.
I've found some lisp phrases and applied those but those don't work at all.

For instance,

```
 
(eval-after-load 'dired
  '(progn
     ;; use the standard Dired bindings as a base
     (evil-make-overriding-map dired-mode-map 'normal t)
     (evil-define-key 'normal dired-mode-map
       "h" 'evil-backward-char
       "j" 'evil-next-line
       "k" 'evil-previous-line
       "l" 'evil-forward-char
       "r" 'dired-do-redisplay))) ; "l"
```

Emacs just runs 'dired-do-kill-lines' as if it doesn't recognize my configuration.
Could you give me some configuration, please?

Comment: Take a look at `evil-add-hjkl-bindings`; there's an example of using it in dired-mode in evil-integration.el. In fact, evil lets you use hjkl in dired-mode by default, which makes me wonder if you're somehow in the wrong state.

Answer (score 2):

What if you press `C-z` until you put yourself in Normal mode (vim mode) ? I do that and I can use those keys to navigate. I use smart-mode-line to see what mode I am in (I don't recall what shows the default mode-line).

You can choose to enter Dired mode in Normal state: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil#Enter_an_emacs_mode_in_a_given_state